# Resting time after specific operation is done

Tags: python, function, date, time

I have two sets which returns a specific value. I would like to carry out an operation on set `apple`. if length of this this set is greater than 0, i woulf like to calculate the elapsed time. If the time passed more than 10 sec, i would like to reset time to zero. Any suggestion to deal this?

```
apple = set([1,5,9,13])
orange = set([2,4,6,8,10])

def fruit(apple,orange): 
    if len(apple)>0:
        time_now = time.time()
    if time_now >10:
        apple.clear()
        time_now == 0
return apple, orange
```

Comment: ``time_now == 0`` is a comparison, not an assignment, use ``time_now = 0`` instead.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?